# Is "投个好胎" a proper set phrase/idiom? What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I'm trying to understand it by finding the meaning behind each word but failed miserably.

What I got from MDBG:

*投 (tóu): to cast / to send / to throw oneself (into the river etc) / to seek refuge / to place oneself into the hands of*

*个 (gè): individual / this / that / size / classifier for people or objects in general*

*好 (hǎo): good / well / proper / good to / easy to / very / so / (suffix indicating completion or readiness) / (of two people) close / on intimate terms / (after a personal pronoun) hello/ to be fond of / to have a tendency to / to be prone to*

*胎 (tāi): fetus / litter / tire / abbr. of 輪胎｜轮胎*

"Casting/investing/putting in a good baby or perhaps tire" just doesn't make any sense...

Does 好胎 here perhaps mean good karma?

Comment: The idioms is similar to the sociology/anthropology meaning of "born in a good family".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

投 (v); plunge into

胎 (n); pregnancy

"**投胎**" (plunge into pregnancy) is a compound word. It means "**to reincarnate**"

*Olden time Chinese believed after people died and became ghosts, some of them were allowed to reincarnate and reborn into the living world*

"投个胎" break up the compound word "投胎" and treating 投 as a verb; 胎 as a noun. When 胎 is a noun, we can add classifier '个' (a)  before it to indicate indefinite

Similar phrase: 投幾次胎 (to reincarnate a few times)

different from "投个胎" (to randomly reborn), we can have “投个好胎", which mean "to reborn into a good family"