# Is 起草 a separable verb?

Tags: word, verbs, separable-verbs

Pleco lists the following example sentence for [起草](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%B5%B7%E8%8D%89):

> 这封信你来**起**个**草**吧。

This indicates 起草 is a separable verb.  And it's possible to find examples online of 起草 being used as a separable verb, such as [我已经**起**了个**草**](http://www.dushu369.com/waiguomingzhu/HTML/79079.html) and [我**起**完**草**](https://www.pinshiwen.com/yuexie/cysl/20190822226001.html).

However, looking at [example sentences from YouDao](http://dict.youdao.com/example/%E8%B5%B7%E8%8D%89%E4%BA%86) we find examples like:

> 他**起草了**一份讲话的概要。
> 他给我**起草了**一篇讲话稿。

It seems this placement of the 了 is inconsistent with 起草 being a separable verb.

**Question**: Is 起草 a separable verb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is 起草 a separable verb?

Yes, in the dictionary《现代汉语词典》, separable words (离合词) are indicated with the symbol "//" in their pinyin, and 起草 is indicated as qǐ//cǎo.

起草 is a verb+object separable word.

verb: 起
object: 草

Anyway, there is an exception to the following general rule:

**GENERAL RULE**

Verb+object separable words cannot be followed by an object.

The following sentence is wrong:

> *昨天我们**谈话**了很多事情。
>
> 谈: verb
> 话: object
> 很多事情: object not allowed

**EXCEPTION**

A few verb+object separable words as 起草 can be followed by an object. They are still verb+object separable words, and all other rules still apply, so we would still say "起了草", "起过草", "起的草", "起完草", "草都没起", "起一起草", "起什么草", etc. But, we can **also** say:

> 他这几天在**起草**一个文件。
> 昨天我们**起草**了一个文件。
>
> 一个文件: object (normally not allowed)

Some other exceptions are:

> 操心, 成交, 出口, 出席, 担心, 发愁, 放心, 进口, 列席, 留神, 留心, 留意, 缺席, 告別, 在意, 注意, 走私.

For more info see [品诗文网](https://m.pinshiwen.com/yuexie/cysl/20190822226001.html)

Answer (score 2):

Read this answer and you would know why a [verb + noun compound word] like 起草 can be separated into [verb and noun] and treated as such

[Is "投个好胎" a proper set phrase/idiom? What does it mean?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/32684/is-%e6%8a%95%e4%b8%aa%e5%a5%bd%e8%83%8e-a-proper-set-phrase-idiom-what-does-it-mean/32685#32685)

> "投个胎" break up the compound word "投胎" and treating 投 as a verb; 胎 as a noun. When 胎 is a noun, we can add classifier '个' (a) before it to indicate indefinite

Similarly, the compound word 起草 (to draft) is a single word, but it is made up of a verb 起(establish) and a noun 草(rough/ draft)

起个草 break up the compound word "起草" and treating 起 as a verb; 草 as a noun.

When 草 is acting as a noun, we can add classifier '个' (a) before it to indicate indefinite

Having 了 in 起草了 indicate 起草 is treated as a single compound word. There is no inconsistency because a separable verb is still treated as a single verb when it is not separated.

Basically, any compound verb that is made up of a verb and a noun is separable

Comment: Honestly, this is blowing my mind.  We're taught separable verb grammar: [游了一个小时的泳](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/41226/8099) (and that 游泳了一个小时 is wrong).  But 起草 can be used with inseparable verb grammar: 起草了一篇讲话稿.  However, we can still write 我已经起了个草 where 起 and 草 are two words!  It's like 起草 is both a separable and inseparable verb.  Wow!!

Comment: 泳 in 游泳 can be either a verb (to swim) or a noun (a swim), but in 游个泳, it has to be treated as a noun;  游泳了一个小时 is wrong but 游泳游了一个小时 is correct; In [ 游泳(v+v)了 ]  one of the verb is redundant, therefore we only say  [ 游(v)了 ]

Comment: We say 游了泳 but not 游泳了,  but we can say 投胎了or 投了胎 and 起草了 or 起了草. because  起草 and 投胎 are made up of verb and noun

Comment: 工作 (inseparable verb) = 工作了, not  工了作;  游泳 (separable verb) = 游了泳, not 游泳了; 起草 (separable / inseparable verb) = 起草了 or 起了草

Answer (score 1):

这封信你来**起个**草吧。"You, (please) **to write/initiate** the preliminary (草) for this letter." Or, "This time, you **write/initiate** the preliminary (草) letter". In both cases, there is only one verb "to write/initiate".